# Building a mockable logging API in Java, the right way

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

I've been reading up on writing testable code and am now trying to put that into practise by refactoring my logging framework API. My main concern is that it should be 1) easy to call from business code, and 2) easily mockable, so that business code can be tested without invoking the real logging and also making it possible to assert that things have been logged or not from said tests.

I've reached a point where it feels pretty testable, but I still feel it can be improved. Please bear with me. This is what I have so far.

```
/*
 * The public API, which has a mockable internal factory responsible for creating log implementations.
 */
public final class LoggerManager {
    private static LoggerFactory internalFactory;
    private LoggerManager() {}

    public static SecurityLogger getSecurityLogger() {
        return getLoggerFactory().getSecurityLogger();
    }
    public static SystemErrorLogger getSystemErrorLogger() {
        return getLoggerFactory().getSystemErrorLogger();
    }
    private static LoggerFactory getLoggerFactory() {
        if (internalFactory == null) 
            internalFactory = new LoggerFactoryImpl();
        return internalFactory;
    }
    public static void setLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory aLoggerFactory) {
        internalFactory = aLoggerFactory;
    }
}
/*
 * Factory interface with methods for getting all types of loggers.
 */
public interface LoggerFactory {
    public SecurityLogger getSecurityLogger();
    public SystemErrorLogger getSystemErrorLogger();
    // ... 10 additional log types
}
public final class LoggerFactoryImpl implements LoggerFactory {
    private final SecurityLogger securityLogger = new SecurityLoggerImpl();
    private final SystemErrorLogger systemErrorLogger = new SystemErrorLoggerImpl();

    public SecurityLogger getSecurityLogger() {
        return securityLogger;
    }
    public SystemErrorLogger getSystemErrorLogger() {
        return systemErrorLogger;
    }
}
```

The API is called like this in business code:

```
LoggerManager.getSystemErrorLogger().log("My really serious error");
```

I would then mock this in unit tests using a TestLoggerFactory, which creates test loggers that simply keeps track of all logging calls and makes it possible to for example do assertNoSystemErrorLogs():

```
LoggerManager.setLoggerFactory(new TestLoggerFactory());
```

Now this works fine, but I still fell as if I'm missing something and it can be made more test friendly. For example, by using the static setLoggerFactory I'm setting the logger factory for all tests, which means one test can actually affect another. So my big question here is, what is the standard way of creating this kind of easily mockable API? Some kind of Dependency Injection?

Please note that the question has more to do with writing an easy to access and use API that is also easy to mock. The fact that my example is a logging framework API is beside the point.

Comment: If you are doing JUnit tests, I would consider using a mock framework like Mockito instead of implementing your own mockable classes. 
Also in a Java EE environment you could use CDI with Qualifiers/Producers to inject your different Loggers instead of using a static Factory.

Comment: And I agree with the first answer - although every programmer *likes* creating a logging framework himself - you are spending your time to re-invent a wheel that already exists. And your version of the wheel will be proprietary, less sophisticated, and much less tested. And of course, it will have less features.

Comment: @Dainesch Sure, I could use Mockito.mock(LoggerFactory.class) instead of new TestLoggerFactory() in the unit test, but that doesn't really change the design of the API, right?

Comment: @GhostCat Fair enough, but the question is more related to testability and writing a framework API that is easy to mock, not whether or not to create your own logging framework. It could just as well be another framework.

Comment: @Dainesh Your CDI example sounds like a a possible solution. Please feel free to concretise it in an answer.

Comment: Two comments: 1) Are you sure you need to mock a logging API? All such APIs can be configured so that logging is written to the console, to a file, or gets simply ignored. And since logging usually is not part of the business functionality of the code being tested, why bother checking that logging calls are made at all? So, consider *not* mocking it. 2) Any logging API *already is* easily mockable, if you're willing to use an existing mocking API that can do the job.

Comment: Well, in my case it's not only about technical logging but also logging of business events such as, say, a purchase. As it can be important that a service performs said logging correctly it is important to be able to mock and assert that the logged information is correct. But, as I wrote in the end of the question, I took logging as the example simply because I'm currently working with it but I'm more interested in good patterns to use when building that type of API that makes it easy to mock/test

Comment: Ok, so logging was just an example, fine. My second point still stands, though: it's not a good idea to design for testability (or worse, for "mockability"); instead, design for simplicity and ease of use. There are different ways to write tests, and mocking is only one option. Personally, I avoid mocking whenever I can, prefering integration tests over isolated unit tests. But when needed, any Java API can be mocked as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asked in the comments to provide a sample using logger injection via CDI. There are many possible implementations, but in order to show how different qualifiers could be used I opted for this sample where I assume that the loggers share the common Logger interface and where different qualifiers are used.

However provided with the case of 10+ possible log types, I would opt for a qualifier using an enum property to decide which logger to inject.

First define your qualifiers (Security, SystemError, ....) to mark which implementation you would want to inject:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER})
public @interface Security {
}
```

Then you have to define how you create the logger implementations. It is a factory, sort of. The implementation can depend on the injection point and values given to the qualifiers. Here for example, I just pass the loggers the class name of the class where it is injected.
The two methods are used to create the different implementations. That can be achieved by applying the qualifiers to the methods.

```
@Singleton
public class LoggerProducer {

    // here perhaps a cache or environment related flags, ...

    @Security
    @Produces
    public Logger getSecurityLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String key = getKeyFromIp(ip);
        return new SecurityLoggerImpl(key);
    }

    @SystemError
    @Produces
    public Logger getSystemErrorLogger(InjectionPoint ip) {
        String key = getKeyFromIp(ip);
        return new SystemErrorLoggerImpl(key);
    }

    private String getKeyFromIp(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return ip.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getCanonicalName();
    }

}
```

Now you can inject your desired logger where you want to use it (see CDI configuration file beans.xml)

```
@Stateless
public class SampleService {

    @Inject
    @Security
    private Logger securityLogger;

    public void doSomething() {
        securityLogger.log("I did something!");
    }

}
```

When unit testing you will still have to mock the logger as you would mock every other injected object, nothing changes using CDI. When integration testing, you could change how/what loggers are produced.

Don't take it personal, but I don't get why to use 10+ different loggers and not use the mechanisms provided by most log frameworks and/or mock frameworks. Perhaps you have good reasons, well, it always helps to know all your options.

---

Edit: Add JUnit sample

To unit test the SampleService we create the following test case using Mockito:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SampleService sample;

    @Mock
    private Logger securityLogger;

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        doThrow(new RuntimeException("Fail")).when(securityLogger).log(anyString());

        sample.doSomething(); // will fail 
    }

}
```

The test is setup up in such a way, that when logger.log is called an exception is thrown.

Comment: Looks nice. So how would you go about mocking the logger in a unit test?
As for the reason of multiple loggers we have MANY different custom log types all filled with different data. Everything from error logs that takes exceptions to request logs with parameters to session logs with session information etc etc. But as I said, I'm more interested in the concept of creating a testable and mockable design.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest improvement might be to use the existing de facto standard implementation agnostic API, which is slf4j.

Comment: How do you know I'm not using it under the hood? The question is about writing an easy to use API accessible from business code that is easy to mock, that it is a logging framework or something else is beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

Also your classes are not thread safe
The `LoggerManager` can create multiple `LoggerFactoryImpl` instances , which I suppose you are trying to make it singleton.
Pay attention to  `getLoggerFactory()`

Comment: Yes I know, I removed all the code that was not strictly related to the question regarding writing easily mockable and testable code to not make the question unnecessarily large.